# Do Iron Golems Regenerate Health?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My player-created NPC village just spawned an Iron Golem, and my pal Endy the Enderman decided to teleport right in to introduce himself (Unlucky for Endy).

I chose to watch the battle rather than get involved, and the Iron Golem took a few hits in the process. It won, but I'm wondering whether it regenerates health, or whether the next hit from a mob is going to down it and leave my poor villagers defenceless until another spawns.

So, do Iron Golems regain health over time? Or Is it possible to "repair" them at least?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Golem)

> Note that they do not regenerate HP but can be healed with a splash
> health potion.

Comment: Somehow I missed this during my cursory glance at the wiki. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't think any mob regenerated.

Comment: @ydobonebi [The wither does](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Wither#Java_Edition)

Answer (score 1):

Iron Golems can't regenerate at the moment, hopefully this is something that will be added in the future.

If you're in creative it works with a splash health potion. In survival it takes a while so I would recommend that you guard your village while you do this.

If you see your Golem get a few more hits and are not sure if your Golem has gone down or *died* look for a red lovely jubbly *flower* and some iron.

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answer.